# PrimeFaces 12 DataExporter decimal numbers xls

Tags: primefaces, primefaces-dataexporter

When updating to PrimeFaces 12, DataExporter presented an error in formatting decimal numbers in xls. Example: 50.00 is being printed 5,000
Note: the attempt below solved the problem locally (win10), but the problem persists on the server.

```html
<f:facet name="header">
    <div align="center">
        <p:outputPanel style="float: right;">
            <h:commandLink id="gerarXls" styleClass="table-button generateXls">
                <p:graphicImage name="/images/table-icons/file-xls.svg"/>
                <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="datatableOrdemServico" fileName="Ordens de Servico"
                                options="#{dataExporterCustomizedView.excelOpt}"/>
            </h:commandLink>
        </p:outputPanel>
    </div>
</f:facet>
<p:column width="50" style="text-align: right"
          sortBy="#{ordemServico.totalGeral}" filterMatchMode="contains" filterBy="#{ordemServico.totalGeral}">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Total OS"/>
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{ordemServico.totalGeral}" >
        <f:convertNumber minFractionDigits="2" locale="pt-BR"/>
    </h:outputText>
</p:column>
```

```java
public class DataExporterCustomizedView implements Serializable {

    private ExcelOptions excelOpt;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        excelOpt = new ExcelOptions();

        excelOpt.setFacetBgColor("#F88017");
        excelOpt.setFacetFontSize("10");
        excelOpt.setFacetFontColor("#0000ff");
        excelOpt.setFacetFontStyle("BOLD");
        excelOpt.setCellFontColor("#00ff00");
        excelOpt.setCellFontSize("8");
        excelOpt.setStronglyTypedCells(true);
        excelOpt.setNumberFormat(new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00"));
        excelOpt.setCurrencyFormat((DecimalFormat) DecimalFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("pt", "BR")));
    }
public ExcelOptions getExcelOpt() {
        return excelOpt;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From this ticket: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/8961

> Setting a custom per cell basis is not supported and is out of scope
> of this issue.
>
> Currently, DataExporter detection feature only considers the property
> "CurrencyFormat" or "DecimalFormat" in ExcelOptions or, if it's not
> defined,  in faces-config.xml.

Or by setting it in faces-config.xml
**faces-config.xml**

```xml
<locale-config>
    <default-locale>pt_BR</default-locale>
</locale-config>
```

**My Guess:**  Your server is in a differnet locale so that is what Faces is defaulting to because you are missing the explicit locale setting in your faces-config.xml.